# "branch ... not fully merged" immediately after fetch

Tags: git, github

The following makes no sense to me

```
% git clone $REPO_URL --branch dev wd
% cd wd
% git fetch origin master:master
From github.com:ghuser/someproj
 * [new branch]      master     -> master
% git branch -d master
error: The branch 'master' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D master'.
```

Note that the above error message occurs on a `git branch -d master` command that happens *immediately* after the `master` branch has been fetched from the remote repo.  Does it mean that `origin` is corrupted somehow?  I can't figure out how this happened.

Comment: What is the goal on deleting the master branch??

Comment: Looks like you're on `dev` when you try that.  If all the commits on `master` aren't merged into `dev`, you'll get that error.

Comment: @iberbeu: no goal, I am just trying to understand what is going on.

Comment: so your real question is "What does 'branch is not fully merged' mean?" -- since it has nothing to do with when your last fetch happened

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning

```
branch is not fully merged
```

comes when the branch you are trying to remove is not merged into another one. This warning saves you from removing a branch and its changes before you merge them, so you don't lose your changes.

In your case it looks like you didn't have the branch 'master' in your computer since you get the message

```
* [**new branch**]      master     -> master
```

So when you downloaded the branch `master` you where on `dev` and then you tried `git branch -d master` but since it was not merged from the point of view of dev you got the message

With `gitk --all` you can see the whole tree and there you will see how the branch master is not merged into another. Hence the message.

If you still want to remove it just use the `-D` command

Comment: he explicitly only got the `dev` branch when he cloned (this is visible in his question) and got the master branch after that. When and where he got the branch is irrelevant to its 'merged' state, though.

Comment: that is what I meant. I don't know which is actually his 'master' branch. If he changed it is normal that this error happens

Comment: OK, my confusion comes from interpreting the *error* message as somehow preventing me from losing work, in the form of unrecoverable commits.  This is what made the situation seem non-sensical, since I couldn't have possibly made any changes.  Plus the fact that the message is labeled "error", which seems excessive in light of what it actually means: it's like having an error message every time one uses `rm` because one may be deleting a file that one does not have a duplicate of.

Comment: @iberbeu you seem to be confusing the fact that 'master' is usually the "default" branch of a repo with the situation here. in Git, all branches are equal; "not fully merged" is always referring to the current branch.

Comment: to elaborate, there is not even a "default" branch in git. this terminology is used by Github and other hosting services because they need some kind of default for displaying the repo. Git first creates a branch called 'master' as default, but this branch is in no way special and can simply be renamed.

Comment: I think I have expressed it wrong. I edited it, I hope it ist better this way

Answer (score 8):

A branch (call it `A`, would be 'master' in your case) is considered "fully merged" into the currently checked out branch (call it `B`, would be 'dev' in your case) iff the [tip of] `A` is an ancestor of B.

The error you get has thus nothing to do with how you cloned the repo or when you fetched. It merely means that 'master' has commits which are not yet contained in your current branch 'dev'.

Comment: It does not have to be merged into the currently checked-out branch. A branch `A` is considered fully merged if *any* other branch `B` points to a commit that has the commit `A` points to as its (direct or indirect) parent. I.e. if `A` can be removed and you still have a way to get to the commit using branches.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the simple explanation. All I had to do is check out a branch which contained the all commits from 'master' and the "error" was gone.